# I am trying to rename a batch of files in numerical order, but they are showing results out of order?

Tags: python

I am trying to renumber a large number of photos (566) which I exported from Apple Photos. I was able to renumber them from the odd titles assigned to them, but they aren't numbered in the order of their position. i.e, photo 1 is numbered 184, not 1, and photo 566 is numbered 72, not 566 (etc).

This is what I did, which successfully renumbered the photos, but they are still in completely the wrong title order. The order in the file is correct, the titles do not reflect the order.

```
import os, os.path

data_dir_path = "/path"

for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(data_dir_path)):
    new = "HRC-" + str(count) + '.jpg' #new file name
    src = os.path.join(data_dir_path, filename) #path source
    dst = os.path.join(data_dir_path, new) #path destination
    os.rename(src, dst)

#print(src, "=", dst)
```

I also tried this:

```
import os, os.path
data_dir_path = "/path"

i=0
for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(data_dir_path)):
    new = "HRC-" + str(count) + '.jpg' #new file name
    src = os.path.join(data_dir_path, filename) #path source
    dst = os.path.join(data_dir_path, new) #path destination
    # where new was f'{str(count)}.jpg'
    #os.rename(src, dst)
    i += 1

print(src, "=", dst)
```

to similar results.

Comment: `os.listdir()` does not have any guaranteed ordering of the list it returns.  You'll need to sort it yourself if you want a particular order.

Comment: This is exactly correct- the mistake I made was assuming the order. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `sorted(os.listdir(data_dir_path))` could work (difficult to know without seeing how the input and desired output look like).

Comment: Yes- I made the mistake of not sorting first before ordering. D'oh!